# socket_read() returns only headers, not the actual response

Tags: php, sockets

I'm running

```
$data = socket_read($socket, 2048, PHP_BINARY_READ);
```

that should return a string like this

```
// $data == ' 1840 kg G 008765 A '
```

but instead it returns

```
Original response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 19 Feb 2003 09:00:00 GMT
Server: MoxaHttp/1.0
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-type: text/html
Content-length: 450
```

which is looks like headers of the data returned.

socket_send is configured correctly, we have other clients with same settings and they return correct values.

Can you please say what's the problem, and why i'm not getting expected string?

UPDATE:

I repeated socket_read() multiple times to read full string it it is:

```
Original response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 19 Feb 2003 09:00:00 GMT
Server: MoxaHttp/1.0
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-type: text/html
Content-length: 450
Set-Cookie: ChallID=1656
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>NPort Web Console</TITLE></HEAD> <FRAMESET rows=57,1* frameborder=NO> <FRAME name=top scrolling=NO target=contents src=top.htm noresize> <FRAMESET cols=200,*> <FRAME name=contents target=main src=contents.htm> <FRAME name=main src=main.htm marginwidth=0 marginheight=0 scrolling=auto> </FRAMESET> <NOFRAMES><BODY background=bg.gif><P>This page uses frame, but your browser doesn't support.</P></BODY> </NOFRAMES> </FRAMESET></HTML>
```

so it's look like it returns some different things, that are suppose to be read by other program.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong: are you trying to connect to a specific host, send a request and expect an answer? The reason i ask this is because the part where you initialise `$socket` is not included in your question.

Comment: @Fin yes, all right. The initialization is regular - $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP); socket_connect($socket, $host, $port); socket_send($socket, chr(005), strLen(chr(005)), 0);

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the same code on different machines (but one) returns the same result from only one host. What about the network configuration on that one machine that gives problems? Could it be configured differently? Or maybe the router/firewall that blocks something?

Comment: @Fin Yes, all other machines work fine, and perhaps they are configured differently, i'm just curious about from what part the problem comes from, whether it's my PHP code or something on device side.

Comment: It's what you send to the server before reading out the socket. You're either sending a malformed request, or sending it to the wrong URL. Or possibly the service expects a specific user-agent to be present in the request.

Comment: You're seeing HTTP headers in that socket_read. Like if you're getting an HTTP response instead of a plain text message in your socket.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried?:

```
echo "Reading response:\n\n";
$buf = 'This is my buffer.';
if (false !== ($bytes = socket_recv($socket, $buf, 2048, MSG_WAITALL))) {
    echo "Read $bytes bytes from socket_recv(). Closing socket...";
} else {
    echo "socket_recv() failed; reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
}
socket_close($socket);
```